# Zurb Foundation tooltip stays on the screen

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation-5

zurb foundation tooltip stays on the screen after component removal/insertion: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jutapilune/2/edit

There is a number of hacks floating around, but I wonder - maybe Ember community has resolved that issue already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
actions: {
    remove: function(){
        this.$('button').remove();
    }
}
```